# Merging old duplicates?

Tags: discussion, merging

*New to meta, so apologies for any breaches of etiquette.*

I've just noticed that these two old questions are duplicates:

[Smallest permutation representation of a finite group?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16858/smallest-permutation-representation-of-a-finite-group)

[Smallest n for which G embeds in $S_n$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48928/smallest-n-for-which-g-embeds-in-s-n)

It might not matter too much, except that they are still attracting occasional answers / comments, with neither one's responses being wholly subsumed by the other (the only answerer of the first question also answered the second, but the two answers are not duplicates).

I doubt I am the only person who has looked at one question without being aware of the existence of the other. It would of course be possible to add a note to each question linking to the other, but would it perhaps be better to merge both into a single question?