# What should you do if you find old duplicates?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, vote-to-close, exact-duplicates

Sometimes I discover that "old" MO questions are duplicates of even older MO questions.

Two examples:

- Embarrassingly, I found out that my own question: [Formula for number of permutations less than a given permutation in weak order](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325242/formula-for-number-of-permutations-less-than-a-given-permutation-in-weak-order) is the same as a question from 5 years earlier: [Principal Order Ideals in the Weak Bruhat Order](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173042/principal-order-ideals-in-the-weak-bruhat-order).
- This question: [How do I determine the number of "second degree" derangements?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371538/how-do-i-determine-the-number-of-second-degree-derangements) (which is actually relatively recent) is a duplicate of this question from 7 years ago: [Number of Permutations?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144899/number-of-permutations).

Now, I can vote to close the newer questions as duplicates (which I've tried to do)- but because these questions are not active, they are very unlikely to attract enough votes for this to work.

I wouldn't want these questions outright *removed*, of course, since often the duplicate questions contain non-duplicative answers.

In fact, what I have done so far is put a comment (in both of the questions) linking the two questions which are duplicates. This should help somebody who discovers the question later and might want to see all the various perspectives on it.

So: what should be done in cases like these?

(A related question would be: are there ways to improve detection of duplicate questions, especially as the database of questions answered on MO continues to grow larger and larger. As you can see in these examples, the "original" questions are from quite a while ago.)

Comment: Isn't a simple if perhaps unsatisfying answer that, if a question isn't active enough to attract more votes to close as duplicate, then it's not really disturbing anyone to have that unnoticed duplicate around?

Comment: It is possible to merge two questions so that "the various perspectives" don't get lost. I'm sure this has to be done by a moderator, so I suppose the thing to do is to flag for moderator attention and explain that you want to see the questions merged (or, the answers to the duplicate appended to the older question).

Comment: Since Gerry Myerson mentioned merging, I will add a link to this: [What is the procedure to initiate merging of questions?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4071) (Of course, even if two questions are duplicates, merging is *not always* suitable/possible.)

Comment: Re: *because these questions are not active, they are very unlikely to attract enough votes for this to work.* I will just remind you that if you vote to close some question, it is then pushed into the [close votes review queue](https://mathoverflow.net/review/close/history). On a site which is healthy, there is enough users who visit review queues and they will notice the question. (And, based on their judgement, they might vote for or against closing as a duplicate.)

Comment: Related SEDE queries: [Recent close reviews](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1272909/recent-reviews-of-a-specific-type?type=2) and [Recent invalidated close reviews](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1304510/recent-reviews-specific-type-and-state-active-completed-invalidated?type=2&state=3) (The data in SEDE are updated only once a week, so the link in the previous comment is better - but it will only show the full review history to 10k+ users. Results of SEDE queries can be seen by anybody.)

Comment: cross-linking seems a good solution, if needed add explication why its a duplicate, as that might not be obvious ...